# Creating a highlight when clicking specfic elements, and hiding others when not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code, I cant figure out a more efficient way to get the desired result but more importantly, I cant figure out a way to hide highlights when a different element is clicked. This is a calendar script, where when (Sunday Monday Tuesday) are clicked, both those days are highlighted with a background color change and the next week is also highlighted. Also, when (Weds,Thurs,Fri,Sat) are clicked, they, as well as the next next week is highlighted. Can anyone help me out? I havent been able to wrap my head around this, everything I do breaks.

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/ycxhaxop/

```
$(".w1f").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week2').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w1l").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week3').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w2f").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week3').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w2l").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week4').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w3f").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week4').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w3l").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week5').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w4f").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week5').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w4l").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week6').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w5f").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
$('#week6').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
```

Comment: Could you explain the requirement in more detail?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ycxhaxop/

When (sun,mon,tue) are clicked, it highlights the entire next week. When (wed,thur,fri,sat) are click it highlights the entire week after that. The problem is, the highlighting only goes away when you click the original element. I want it to go away when you click a separate element.

Answer (score 0):

i do changes for Sunday, Monday, Tuesday.Please check is it working

```
$(".w1f").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
 $('.w2f').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w1l").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
 $('#week3').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w2f").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
 $('.w3f').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w2l").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
 $('#week4').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w3f").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
 $('.w4f').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w3l").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
 $('#week5').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w4f").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
 $('#week5').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w4l").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
 $('#week6').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
$(".w5f").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
 $('#week6').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
})
```

Comment: This doesnt help at all, this removes functionality

Answer (score 0):

comment the toggle class for the week..

```
<script>
    $(".w1f").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
        //$('#week2').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w1l").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week3').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w2f").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week3').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w2l").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week4').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w3f").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
      //  $('#week4').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w3l").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week5').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w4f").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week5').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w4l").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("last").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week6').toggleClass("nnweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })
    $(".w5f").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("first").toggleClass("trans");
       // $('#week6').toggleClass("nextweek").toggleClass("trans");
    })

</script>
```

Comment: This doesnt help at all, this removes functionality